# Paralle backup threads in postgres

Tags: multithreading, postgresql, database-administration

I am taking dump of tables with pg_dump and using option -j and directory format for parallel backups. I have only 2 tables and giving -j 8, means 8 parallel threads. I just want to confirm if all 8 threads will contribute in taking backup of 2 tables or only 2 threads will work and others will remain idle?
Crux of question is : If it is one thread for one table or all threads for as many table as we mentioned in command?

Comment: Only 2 will be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only one thread can work on a single table (each table is backed up in its own file, and it would be difficult for two threads to write to the same dump file concurrently).

So 6 of your 8 threads will be idle.

Comment: How about improving pg_dump to write to multiple files, each forming a part of the table? So instead of a single thread writing to 8071.dat.gz, two threads would write to 8071.dat.gz and 8071-2.dat.gz each. And pg_restore would understand this split format accordingly.

Comment: @Rihad That's what partitioning is about :^)

Comment: great, didn't know about it) It has its cons and limitations while setting it up. From my non-expert POV dumping single huge table in parallel shouldn't be too difficult, considering the serializable transaction isolation level pg_dump uses. I'd do it by dividing the count(*) from the table by the number of parallel workers)

Comment: @Rihad Yes, it could work in principle, but you'd probably have to invent a new dump format.